# Android Studio - настроить разворачивание кода

Tags: android-studio, настройка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить Android Studio так, чтобы при открытии нового файла код разворачивался сразу? А то есть некоторые куски кода, которые отображаются в свёрнутом виде и приходится каждый раз клацать на "плюс", чтобы его развернуть.

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 4):

**Горячие клавиши свернуть развернуть:**

Для Windows:

- Ctr + -/+   Фолдинг, свернуть/развернуть
- Ctr + Shift + -/+    Фолдинг, свернуть/развернуть все

Для Mac:

- COMM + SHFT + -/+ Фолдинг, свернуть/развернуть
- COMM + SHFT + -/+ Фолдинг, свернуть/развернуть все

**Настройки если английская IDE:**

> Settings >> Editor >> General >> Code Folding

В IDE специально сделаны фолдинги, чтобы их не разворачивать, иначе будет очень сложно взаимодействовать с кодом. Обычно сворачивают аннотации и куски кода, которые не используются, поэтому по умолчанию IDE не разворачивает фолдинги.

Comment: Подскажите, какой именно пункт настройки отвечает за это?

Comment: Как-то у меня немного по-другому [скриншот](http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/3/4/5/Bezimyanni_1594709_26369345.png)

Comment: @Gamlet, разные версии секунду

Comment: @Gamlet, проверил все настройки, нельзя сделать по умолчанию, чтобы загружались открытые фолдинги

Comment: Печально. Ладно, благодарю за старания...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно сработать.

Comment: Не помогает. Стояла галочка, и убирал галочку... всё равно при открытии файла часть кода свёрнут в "плюс"

Comment: @Gamlet Я думаю, что Вы догадались перезапустить программу. Странно, потому что у меня, на сколько я помню, именно это и решило ту же проблему, которая у Вас возникла.

Comment: Изначально этот пункт был отмечен и код сворачивался. Я отметку убрал, изменения принял, программу перезапустил - код всё равно свёрнут.

Answer (score 0):

Сочетания клавиш,

Для Windows:

```
  свернуть всё: CTRL + SHFT + '-'
  развернуть всё:   CTRL + SHFT + '+'
```

Для Mac:

```
  свернуть всё: COMM + SHFT + '-'
  развернуть всё:   COMM + SHFT + '+'
```

Comment: Это горячие клавиши. А как сделать, чтобы через настройки это происходило, чтобы при открытии файла код разворачивался сразу?